# Access startup form locked GUI

Tags: ms-access, vba

I just had an interesting experience with a startup form in MS Access 2010. I designed a login form and when I thought I was done I set my startup form to be the login form I'd just created. I then closed Access and reopened it but my login form did not appear. Instead the whole GUI was locked. I cannot click on anything.

My form was working during my tests before I set it as a startup form and reloaded Access. How can I either remove my form as a startup object or get the use of my GUI back?

Comment: from http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/bypass-startup-options-when-you-open-a-database-HA010226996.aspx: *To bypass startup options, do the following:
Hold down the SHIFT key while opening your database.*

Comment: ah interesting! Well looks like I have options for next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure exactly why this series of events caused my GUI freeze up but this is what I did to solve it. I was able to go into the VBA IDE with alt+F11. In the Immediate window I typed

```
for i = 11 to Application.CurrentDb.Properties.Count - 1: Debug.Print Currentdb.Properties(i) & "::" & i: next i
```

This let me figure out that item 49 in the `Properties` collection is the startup form. Again in the Immediate window I typed

```
Application.CurrentDb.Properties(49) = "(none)"
```

and hit enter.

I was then able to save, close and reopen my DB with no startup form!

I later tried to set my login form as the startup form again (having not changed anything) and it worked fine. It seems like something must have become corrupt somewhere when I set the startup form the first time.